# Create animation matching with music bit rate

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, avaudioplayer, mpmusicplayercontroller

I want to create an animation which will match the playing music, like if the music is soft music (like classical) animation will be slow, if music is fast (metal/rock) animation will be fast.

Is there any way to do it in iOS programmatically? Like using `AVAudioPlayer` or any other class is it possible detect music type(soft/fast) so I can match animation with it?

Comment: Apple's frameworks don't cover this kind of thing. Google "bpm detection".

Comment: thanks a lot , i am going to search for this.

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/36475/how-to-make-a-music-visualizer-in-ios  check this out . it might be of help